# How to calculate the derivate of activation functions for artificial neural nets

Tags: neural-network

When using the sigmoid activation function I understand that the derivative is calculated by output*(1-output). But how is this determined? How do I get from the sigmoid function 1/(1+e^(-x)) to determining that the derivative should be output*(1-output)?

For example if I want to determine the derivative of atan(x) or atan(x) with output scaled to the range 0-1 (atan(x)*0.3183098861837907+0.5), how do I determine this derivative for use in training the neural net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems to me like this is more of a maths related question than a coding one, but here you go anyways.

- For the sigmoid function:

[image]

where [image]

If you compute its derivative:

[image]

and [image]

Thus:

[image]

Remember, ***x*** is the input, and ***f*** is the output. Which is why you get your "output*(1-output)"

For other activation functions, you'll just have to compute the derivative first and then code it. Usually though, it won't have a nice form like the one above.

- For the other part of your question, what you have is something of this form:

[image]

If you compute its derivative (and this will work for any function u(x) that is scaled and offset), you get:

[image]

Put simply, the ***b*** part is a constant so it disappears when derived and the ***a*** is a constant coefficient so it remains unchanged when derived.

In your case, since:

[image]

the derivative you're looking for is:

[image]

On a personal note, this is pretty simple maths and I would strongly suggest you focus on understanding these before you start using neural networks ;)

Cheers